# Menus unrensponsive after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: 13.10

After a 13.10 upgrade which seems otherwise allright, I am experiencing some delay and unresponsiveness when clicking on menus in the global bar.
This happens on two computers of mine, both upgraded to 13.10.
I am wondering if, before going through a clean install, there is something I can try (like trashing some preference or uninstalling some package). I know it's nearly impossible for anybody to know what my issue is - must be something I installed on both pcs, but what? - but maybe you can point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: Same here. Very frustrating. When I use the keyboard shortcuts to open the menus, sometimes they appear in the very top-left on the screen. I've noticed the utility-panel-service spike to 25% CPU when I click a menu item and wait a second or two for it to open (if at all).

Comment: In compiz settings, disable animation. It made things better for me

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365666/ubuntu-13-10-unity-menu-very-slow-and-unresponsive) might be of help. It looks like there is a patch in progress - maybe it's already out. Try updating and see if it fixes the problem.