# Unity menu very slow and unresponsive

Tags: unity

I have a HP G62 laptop with Intel Pentium processor and ATI graphics. 
Since upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10, my Unity menu is very slow and unresponsive. I am using proprietary driver for my graphics

For example, I'm switching between Gimp and Chrome. When I switch to Gimp, I will be stuck with Chrome menu at the top of the screen. It is really annoying and it is just one of many bugs that came up with 13.10.

Any ideas? Should I just revert to default driver?

Comment: Could it be that this only happens when Gimp is opened? In that case it could be this bug:
[Menus are very slow to load](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1245155) If so, it would be good to add yourself to the list of affected users and maybe write a comment describing your machine and your situation. This would help raise attention for the bug and –more importantly– for it being solved.

Comment: Mostly with gimp, but also with Sublime Text 3

Comment: I don't think changing the driver will help, NVidia & Intel people are reporting the same issue (e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/368541/laggy-graphics-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10). The best conversation to watch on this issue is at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877

Comment: when you disable unity plugin on compiz settings manager, and enable again, works fine, maybe be a light for anyone else, maybe on a computer under amd the unity plugin be loaded after amd drivers or native drivers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This fix for this issue got released on 2013-11-01 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877/comments/73). Just keep an eye out for gtk+3.0 in the Softare Updates and apply it once it arrives on your machine. I can confirm that this fix solves it for me.

Comment: Downvote removed, have a nice day :)

Comment: How do you install it before t lands in the official repos? Terrible bug indeed

Comment: I still suffer from this issue to this day :( very bad bug

Comment: Me too. Any word on when this update hits the repos?

Comment: I am still experiencing it

Answer (score -1):

I have run into similar issues when upgrading to new Ubuntu versions. Usually, ATI Graphics cards don't usually play well with Ubuntu. Try reverting back to the default driver or look for other updated version that might work with your system. Good luck!