# Laggy Graphics After Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: graphics, 13.10, intel-graphics

I noticed some issues concerning the graphics after I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. More specifically:

- Dash tends to be more "laggy" than it used to be.
- When I switch desktops you can clearly see the screen going frame by frame.
- Menu bar is also "laggy". When I open GIMP, the menu bar is useless after a while - it takes seconds to refresh.

The problems seem to appear after some seconds of use. When I boot the system everything works fine, until some more graphics-intensive program starts (Firefox, GIMP, etc).

**/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p** reports:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 9.2.1

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

I use an Asus Zenbook UX31A with:

- Intel® Core i5 Ivy Bridge
- Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 4000
- Intel® HM76 Express Chipset

Thank you in advance for any answer!

Comment: I did the same upgrade on my Lenovo X1 Carbon and am experiencing the same thing. Other threads talk about updates to NVida/ATI drivers being necessary, but so far no [SOLVED] responses to those suggestions.

I've narrowed it down to the unity-panel-service eating all the CPU, and there's a converstaion on launchpad as this problem gets solved: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877

Comment: I posted my answer to this on http://askubuntu.com/questions/365666/ubuntu-13-10-unity-menu-very-slow-and-unresponsive/369294 - (because I suspect the mods will likely flag this question as duplicate to that.)