# How to install a single package from Launchpad

Tags: package-management

How do I download and install a proposed ubuntu package from Launchpad? I am technical but not THAT technical so if you could give me a hint it would be much appreciated.

To give you a background on this, I am affected by a very annoying issue where my menus become unresponsive (see [Unity menu very slow and unresponsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365666/ubuntu-13-10-unity-menu-very-slow-and-unresponsive)), and it happens on both my main machines -terrible bug if you ask me.
This issue renders Ubuntu unusable at times, and I've read on that same page that a fix might be available in the new gtk3 package (3.8.6).

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are refering to this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1199877

You just have to enable proposed updates and update, you can disable them after that.

Software Center>Edit>Sources

Answer (score 0):

To install a single package just add the PPA, update the package list and install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:some/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install package
```

Done

Comment: mmmh it's an Ubuntu package though, what would the PPA be? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0

Comment: @Akmur that is not a PPA, but the package itself that it's in the repository.

Comment: Yes, and I need to know how to install it. The version I have (looking at synaptic) is 3.8.4, I want to try 3.8.6

Comment: If that's the case you must upgrade to Saucy.

Comment: I am on saucy :)

Comment: Edit your question because we derailed too much of the original question. Please remember the "XY problem" and state your goal instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install one package from ubuntu-proposed is to enable the package in Software sources. Then create the file /etc/apt/preferences with this content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=saucy-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400
```

To do so you may open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences`. Copy any paste the contents above, save and close. This prevents all packages from the proposed source to be installed.

Then to install the package you need, just type `sudo apt-get install packagename/saucy-proposed` in a terminal.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed